# Multiple query inside foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: laravel, loops, laravel-5, foreach

I've been scratching my head over this since last night. I have this function on my controller:

```
 public function generate_documents($id)
    {
        $contract = Contract::find($id);
        $booking_ids = $contract->booking_id;
        $booking_ids = json_decode($booking_ids);
        $bookings = Booking::find($booking_ids);
   }
```

`$booking_ids` returns a json of ids that are stored in the database. I then find the booking records based on the IDs.

```
foreach($bookings as $booking) {
   $asset = Omg_asset::where('id', $booking->omg_asset)->first();
}
```

Here's the part where I am expecting 3 results but only the last one gets returned on my view. I tried this method:

```
$asset = '';
foreach($bookings as $booking) {
   $asset .= Omg_asset::where('id', $booking->omg_asset)->first();
}
```

But whenever I try to retrieve the values on my view, it's returning a json containing all the records I need and I can't access it via index.

Attaching a screenshot for better context:

[image]

Here's my code on my view by the way:

```
@foreach($bookings as $booking)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $asset }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Here's the error thrown whenever I try to do `{{ $asset['asset_name'] }}` on view:

`"Illegal string offset 'asset_name'"`

I haven't used Laravel in a long time so I would really appreciate your help. If there's also a better way to do this, I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this. Make `$asset` an array. Like `$asset = [];
foreach($bookings as $key => $booking) {
   $asset[$key] = Omg_asset::where('id', $booking->omg_asset)->first();
}` And while displaying in view `@foreach($bookings as $key => $booking)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $asset[$key] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach`

Comment: Your response returned the expected results. Thank you so much!

Comment: It would be better to use @DigitalDrifter's answer if you can. Because your method will run `n` number of DB queries inside the loop where his answer will only run one query for the same.